# Ajax error while creating views

Tags: views, ajax

views are created successfully, now i am not allowed to make change any changes to the view neither i am able to add fields apply filters. Any action i do on the view i am getting a alert message as below.

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred 
>   HTTP Result Code: 200
>   Debugging information follows
>   Path:/admin/structure/views/ajax/display/testimonials/block/row_plugin
>   StatusText:OK
>   a=("44,152,171,160,170...... so on a large number list")

My view Screen looks like this

[image]

I am not sure why i am getting these question marks on edit view

Comment: try to export and import your view

Comment: Do you have jQuery update module installed ?

Comment: @NikhilM: i am not using any such module